# jQuery cross domain external URL content into WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress website (Colormag pro theme)

I am trying to dynamically load in the content from an external (different domain) URL into a blog post.

So, the blogpost HTML is:`<div id="response"></div>`

I then created and placed in my theme's folder grab-URL.php which had:
`<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>`

Finally JQuery:

```
<script> $(function(){var contentURI= 'external-url #element';$('#response').load('grab-URL.php?url='+ contentURI);});</script>
```

And it returns nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: You mention `grab-URL.php` in your question, but you're loading `grab.php` in your code. Is this a typo, or am I missing something? What errors, if any, are in your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: apologies, typo, will correct in question